# How to clear an "isolate" variable when reset is pushed in R Shiny

Tags: shiny

I saw the following code here on StackOverflow.  When you enter values into X and Y, the sum is calculated, and the message "X + Y = " is displayed.  However, when you reset, the "X + Y = " message still appears from the previous example.  How can I clear that message, please?

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id="form",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("x","X",0),
      numericInput("y","Y",0)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      column(width=6,actionButton("calc", "Calculate")),
      column(width=6,actionButton("reset", "Reset")), 
      br(),br(),br(),
      textOutput("sum"))
  )
))


# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sum <- renderText({
    req(input$calc)
    isolate(paste("X + Y =", input$x + input$y))
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    reset("form")
      })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(id="form",
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                numericInput("x","X",0),
                numericInput("y","Y",0)
            ),
            mainPanel(
                br(),
                column(width=6,actionButton("calc", "Calculate")),
                column(width=6,actionButton("reset", "Reset")), 
                br(),br(),br(),
                textOutput("sum"))
        )
    ))


# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues()


    output$sum <- renderText({
        req(values$calc_text)
    })

    observeEvent(input$calc, {
        values$calc_text <- paste("X + Y =", input$x + input$y)
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset, {
        reset("form")
        values$calc_text <- ''
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am unsure why you need the `isolate()` so I've left it out but you can add it back in.

Comment: This is perfect.  It does exactly what I need.  Thank you!